# UWP App Fails to Load mrt100_app.dll, SharedLibrary.dll. and Other Necessary Dependency Files When BIOS Secure Boot is Enabled

Tags: uwp, dependencies, dism

I have a provisioned appx package of a UWP app that is certified by Microsoft which I installed using `DISM` with /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage (adding the required dependencies using `/DependencyPackagePath`)

I found out that when the BIOS secure boot is enabled, the app crashes and from the Process Monitor, it seems that the shared libraries like `mrt100_app.dll` and `SharedLibrary.dll` (Microsoft.VCLibs and Microsoft.NET related libraries) are not found. This does not happen when BIOS secure boot is disabled.

I confirmed using `Get-AppxPackage` that all the dependencies are installed, and since these these dependency files are also certified by Microsoft, they shouldn't they be accessible and allowed to run as well? I need to configure the app to install and run fine regardless if secure boot is enabled or disabled. I would like to hear some ideas to secure that.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, could you mind share a [mcve] for us?

Comment: Hello there, sorry, I contemplated on doing this, but in the end I could not downsize the app because it requires a lot of dependencies. Disabling those may be a bit tedious on my end. But fortunately, we have found the problem. I will explain further in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the UWP app does not have a signed [SCCD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-driver-developers#preparing-the-signed-custom-capability-descriptor-sccd-file), causing the app to crash during launch. We have confirmed the issue by installing the app via MS Store, while secure boot is enabled. MS Store throws an error:

> 0x800701C8: While preparing to process the request, the system failed
> to register the windows.capability extension due to the following
> error: The custom capability's SCCD has an invalid catalog.

Other debug information that had clues leading to security issues come from remote debugging an installed version of the app. A `FailFast Exception` is seen on the CallStack with the error:

> The class is configured to run as a security id different from the
> caller